# Search AWS CLI output and save to variable

Tags: batch-file, amazon-web-services, windows-7, aws-cli

I'm very new to batch files, but I'm trying to use one to automate some AWS CLI instance-creation.

What I have is pretty simple so far -- I have a command in my `.bat` file that will run the `run-instances` command:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --dry-run --image-id %ami_id% --key-name %keypair% --security-group-ids %security_group% --instance-type "r3.large" --subnet-id %az1b_subnet%
```

This command takes a little bit to run, but will eventually (without the `--dry-run`) return json about the created instance(s).  I'd like to search that json output and save the `instance-id` to a variable so that I can use it to tag my newly created instance with the `ec2 create-tags` command.

Any thoughts on how I could do that?  My first attempt was to add `> test.txt` to the end of the above command and then search through the json and set the variable. However, the `test.txt` is created instantly before the CLI command has finished and returned its output.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen/tried [the examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html)?

Comment: Huh, I actually didn't know that was a thing. Pretty new to AWS CLI as well...looks like that'll be a much easier way to go. Thanks!

Comment: @wOxxOm Hmm, so since I won't know the instance-id until the command returns its output, this doesn't seem like a good way to go. Is there a way to make sure that the first command it fully executed and then search though it and set the instance-id variable?

Comment: Yes, use `for /f %%a in ('aws command to show the id --output text') do set AWS_ID=%%a` and then you can use `%AWS_ID%` in subsequent commands. The exact format of `for` command depends on the output of `aws`, of course. I don't use it, so can't be of immediate help without seeing the output.

Comment: No problem, I will look into it. The main problem I was running into was that the output of the AWS CLI command takes a little while to come back.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) has a `--query` parameter that can be used to specify the output fields. Combined with `--output text`, it can provide a list of Instance IDs.

Here's a script, assuming that only one instance is started per `run-instances` call (otherwise a loop would be required):

```
ID=`aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-xxxxxxxx --instance-type t1.micro --query 'Instances[0].InstanceId' --output text`

aws ec2 create-tags --resources $ID --tags Key=Name,Value=WebServer
```

Comment: love this answer.

Comment: In my case, I've to fetch two values from the response, How do i do that ?

Comment: @AppuMistri You could probably save the initial output into a variable, then extract the two values from that response. Feel free to create a new Question and somebody will probably have an answer.

Comment: this doesn't work with aws-cli(v2) docker. I even unsuccessfully tried forwarding 2>&1 as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38784771/docker-run-output-to-bash-variable-strange-behaviour