# `docker run` output to bash variable - strange behaviour

Tags: bash, variables, docker

I'm seeing some strange behaviour getting the output from `docker run` into a bash variable.

Simple example:

```
#!/bin/bash

PWD=$(docker run --rm -ti ubuntu pwd 2>&1)
# also tried with PWD=`docker run ...` with same behaviour
echo $PWD
echo abc $PWD
echo abc $PWD xyz
```

output

```
/
abc /
 xyz/
```

The problem is on the last `echo`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to modify the `docker run --rm -ti ubuntu pwd 2>&1` with `docker run --rm ubuntu pwd 2>&1`
probabilly the interactive and tty mode doesn't work fine in a shell variables

Comment: bingo! It's always those tiny mistakes that produce the weirdest behaviour. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: this didn't slved for me :D

Answer (score 1):

Dockers `-t` option allocates a pseudo terminal for the process to output to. A TTY uses a CRLF for a line ending unlike the usual LF in unix.

The " xyz" in your example output is overwriting the rest of the text from the start of the line due to the carriage return stored in the variable.

The `od` utility can dump the hex or octal values.

```
$ docker run -t busybox pwd | od -b
0000000   057 015 012                                                    
0000003
```

`057 = /` `015 = CR` `012 = LF`

Then the normal output.

```
$ docker run busybox pwd | od -b
0000000   057 012                                                        
0000002
```

Remove the `-t` and possibly check for errors rather than redirecting `stderr` to `stdout`. `-i` is not required unless the process requires `stdin`.

```
PWD=$(docker run --rm ubuntu pwd)
[ "$?" == "0" ] || exit 1
echo "[$PWD]"
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra info! Really useful to know.

Answer (score 0):

The characters `\r\n` are present in the output:

```
$ docker run --rm -ti ubuntu pwd 2>&1 > /tmp/docker.out
$ cat -A /tmp/docker.out 
/^M$
$ python -c "import sys; print repr(sys.stdin.read())" < /tmp/docker.out 
'/\r\n'
```

Also, don't rely on the output for `docker run`, because if the `ubuntu image` is not already present, it will also be pulled and the messages of "Pulling image" will be part of the output.